# Create a dynamic variable with letters and numbers in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have many lines of almost identical code, where the only part that varies is the variable name's letter and number and related get_user_meta key. I would to dynamically create the variables in a more efficient way. (The pattern will continue until Q25G.)

```
    $Q1A = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'key_Q1A', true );
    $Q1B = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'key_Q1B', true );
    $Q1C = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'key_Q1C', true );
    $Q1D = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'key_Q1D', true );
    $Q1E = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'key_Q1E', true );
    $Q1F = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'key_Q1F', true );
    $Q1G = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'key_Q1G', true );      

    $Q2A = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'key_Q2A', true );
    $Q2B = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'key_Q2B', true );
    $Q2C = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'key_Q2C', true );
    $Q2D = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'key_Q2D', true );
    $Q2E = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'key_Q2E', true );
    $Q2F = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'key_Q2F', true );
    $Q2G = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'key_Q2G', true );
```

How can I set these variables dynamically, or otherwise simplify this monstrostiy?

Comment: Search for "associative array" - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php (in other languages an "associative array" is also known as a Hash or a Dictionary). After this there is only one "variable name", eg. `$usermeta` representing many values, each of which is identified by a given key. Once using an array a loop can be used to eliminate the duplicate code. Also, it might make sense (and be more efficient) to _not_ load all the data at once, but defer to usage site..  eg `$user->get_meta('key_Q2G')`.

Comment: And, finally, it may be possible to also eliminate the coding of the 'key' - depending upon larger structure/design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to use arrays

```
$Q = [];
$keys = ["1A", "1B", "1C", "2A"]; // as many as you need
foreach($keys as $key) {
  $Q[$key] = get_user_meta( $user_id, "key_Q$key", true );
}
```

With more information about your use case, we could probably come up with a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: Would 1A, 1B, 1C, etc need to be in quotes?

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry for the oversight. Fixed

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much. It greatly simplifies things and is easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use an associative array as pointed out by shalvah. However, it is possible in PHP to make variable variable names.

In PHP, you can do the following:

```
$index = 'Q1A';
$$index = get_user_meta($user_id, 'key_' . $index, true);
```

You can put this code inside a `while` loop for instance to change the `$index` and go through all options.

Really though, use an associative array.